# BLAS matrix by matrix transpose multiply

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, blas

I have to calculate some products in the form `A'A` or more general `A'DA`, where `A` is a general `mxn` matrix and `D` is a diagonal `mxm` matrix. Both of them are full rank; i.e.`rank(A)=min(m,n)`.

I know that you can save a substantial time is such symmetric products: given that `A'A` is symmetric, you only have to calculate the lower --or upper-- diagonal part of the product matrix. That adds to `n(n+1)/2` entries to be calculated, which is roughly the half of the typical `n^2` for large matrices.

This is a great saving that I want to exploit, and I know I can implement the matrix-matrix multiply within a `for` loop . However, so far I have been using BLAS, which is much faster than any `for` loop implementation that I could write by myself, since it optimizes cache and memory management.

Is there a way to efficiently compute `A'A` or even `A'DA` using BLAS?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for `dsyrk` subroutine of BLAS.

As described in the documentation:

> SUBROUTINE dsyrk(UPLO,TRANS,N,K,ALPHA,A,LDA,BETA,C,LDC)
>
> DSYRK  performs one of the symmetric rank k operations
>
> `C := alpha*A*A**T + beta*C`,
>
> or
>
> `C := alpha*A**T*A + beta*C`,
>
> where  alpha and beta  are scalars, C is an  n by n  symmetric matrix and  A  is an  n by k  matrix in the first case and a  k by n  matrix in the second case.

In the case of `A'A` storing upper triangular is:

```
CALL dsyrk( 'U' , 'T' ,  N , M ,  1.0  , A , M , 0.0 , C , N )
```

For the `A'DA` there is no direct equivalent in BLAS. However you can use `dsyr` in a for loop.

> SUBROUTINE dsyr(UPLO,N,ALPHA,X,INCX,A,LDA)
>
> DSYR   performs the symmetric rank 1 operation
>
> `A := alpha*x*x**T + A`,
>
> where alpha is a real scalar, x is an n element vector and A is an n by n symmetric matrix.

```
do i = 1, M
    call dsyr('U',N,D(i,i),A(1,i),M,C,N)
end do
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dsyrk` routine in BLAS suggested by @ztik is the one for `A'A`. For `A'DA`, one possibility is to use the `dsyr2k` routine which can perform the symmetric rank 2k operations:

> `C := alpha*A**T*B + alpha*B**T*A + beta*C.`

Set `alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.0`, and let `B = DA`. Note that this way assumes your diagonal matrix `D` is real.

Comment: Since D is diagonal, you can also take the square root of it and pre-multiply it against A and then use `dsyrk` on the new matrix.

Answer (score 0):

SYRK is fine for A'A. For A'DA you can use SYMM for one side of it eg V = A'D and then use intel MKL's GEMMT for W = V A. GEMMT is like GEMM except it takes advantage of the fact that the result matrix is symmetric, and thus only has to do roughly half the work.